# Correct way to unset dependent associations before destroying a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model, callback

Say I have 2 ActiveRecord models - `Team`, and `Player`, with a simple parent/child relationship

```rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Rails provides options like `dependent: :destroy` to specify what happens to the child associations when a parent is destroyed.

But what if I don't necessarily want destroy the `Player`s when I `destroy` a `Team`? Instead, I'd like to unset the `team_id` field on each `Player` and then safely `destroy` the `Team`.

**Is there a best practice approach to do that?**

My thought was -

1. Define a `before_destroy` hook on `Team` that clears `Player#team_id` on it's various players
2. Define a `after_rollback` hook on `Team` that handles the case when something had to be rolled back. This would *re-add* the `team_id` to all the `Player` models, basically reversing what we just did

Is #2 necessary? Or does a rollback handle reversing what I already did? And overall is this the best way to approach this?

Would be curious to hear if anyone has a simpler approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players, dependent: :nullify
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
end
```

See [options for the dependent option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-dependent).